# Change the time value of one cell based on another cell using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, date, time, cell

I want to enter Time values to mytable1 in the sample code below and have them reflected -7 hours in mytable2. Considering the time range is 00:00 - 23:59 is also key in this.

```
<table width=600px id="mytable1">
    <tr>
        <td>GMT</td>
        <td>Monday</td>
        <td>Tuesday</td>
        <td>Wednesday</td>
        <td>Thursday</td>
        <td>Friday</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Person A</td>
        <td>09:00 - 17.30</td>
        <td>17:00 - 01.30</td>
        <td>09:00 - 17.30</td>
        <td>17:00 - 01.30</td>
        <td>09:00 - 17.30</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Person B</td>
        <td>09:00 - 17.30</td>
        <td>17:00 - 01.30</td>
        <td>09:00 - 17.30</td>
        <td>17:00 - 01.30</td>
        <td>09:00 - 17.30</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br />
<table width=600px id="mytable2">
    <tr>
        <td>GMT-7</td>
        <td>Monday</td>
        <td>Tuesday</td>
        <td>Wednesday</td>
        <td>Thursday</td>
        <td>Friday</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Person A</td>
        <td>09:00 - 17.30</td>
        <td>17:00 - 01.30</td>
        <td>09:00 - 17.30</td>
        <td>17:00 - 01.30</td>
        <td>09:00 - 17.30</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Person B</td>
        <td>09:00 - 17.30</td>
        <td>17:00 - 01.30</td>
        <td>09:00 - 17.30</td>
        <td>17:00 - 01.30</td>
        <td>09:00 - 17.30</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br />
```

Comment: Is it possible for you to use jQuery for this? That answer will be much simpler.

Comment: Put these together: [Table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement), [String](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) and [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date). Then try something on your own, and if you get stucked, ask a question. SO is not a free coding service.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function cd(val){
 var a = document.getElementById(val.id).value-7;
 document.getElementById("to").value=a;alert(a);
}    
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" name ="dat" id="fu" onChange="cd(this)"/>
<input type="text" name ="dat" id="to"/>
</body>
</html>

Possibly this can help you. Substitute all your table values accordingly
```